# Not allowing access to error page via URL using mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, custom-error-pages

I have my custom error page at `/errors/404.php` and I would like that to be able to be used when apache can't find a file, but I would like it not able to be used by simply requesting the URL `http://mywebsite/error/404.php`.

I currently have a rule that blocks access to all of my php files (because I use URL rewriting to make user-friendly URLs) but this seems to also be stopping apache from reading the error page due to the error page matching the rule to deny access to php files.

How would I do this properly?

The contents of `/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^home/?$       /index.php   [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^lessons/?$    /lessons.php [NC,L]

# Don't allow access to the actual php files.
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.php[\ /?].*HTTP/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$           -                  [R=404,L]

ErrorDocument 404 /errors/404.php
```

Comment: Is there an htaccess file in the `/errors/` directory? I copied and pasted this into a blank htaccess file on a vanilla apache install and it works fine.

Comment: Nope, nothing in `/errors/` except `404.php`. What happens if you try to browse to `/somefile.php`? My one shows the default 404 page and also mentions that there was a 500 error trying to show the 404 page. This is because of the recursion.

Comment: I see my custom error page. You shouldn't get a 500 for internal recursion because the condition checks against `%{THE_REQUEST}` and not `%{REQUEST_URI}`.

Comment: That's what I thought, but it still happens to me :/

Answer (score 1):

You may try this instead:

```
# Don't allow access to the actual php files.
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.php[\ /?].*HTTP/  [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !/errors/404\.php  [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$  -        [R=404,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/errors/404\.php [NC]
RewriteRule .?  -  [F]

ErrorDocument 404 /errors/404.php
```

1. All requests to `.php` files are redirected to `/errors/404.php` script.
2. All requests to non-existent files or directories are redirected to `/errors/404.php` script (The `ErrorDocument 404 /errors/404.php` directive applies in this case).
3. All direct requests to `/errors/404.php` return a 403 Forbidden status code.

Comment: I won't be back at uni until after the weekend, but I'll definitely check it when I get back and let you know.